# All combinations of sums for defined array

Tags: javascript

So i scanned a bit the website and found nothing on it except for permutation but is not really that. What i'm looking for is to input an array of elements `example: [2,5,10]` and get the result of all possible, non duplicate sums. It there any one that can be done? Using the example, the array `[7,10,15]` should be resulted from such function.

Since people think this is a challenge or homework, it is not.
What i tried so far is something like this but i'm stuck:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < multipliers.length;){
        var length = multipliers.length;
        var counter = 0;
        while(++counter <= length){
            var x = 0;
            var sum = multipliers[i] + multipliers[x];
            x++;
            console.log(sum)
        }
  i++;
}
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Like for our example, having `2+5`, `2+10`, `5+10` and `2+5+10` ? I don't nderstand

Comment: why not 0, 2, 5, 7, 10, 12, 15, 17?

Comment: This sounds like homework. You need to show what you have tried. This isn't a free coding or homework service. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because he's asking to solve a challenge

Comment: the following function should do 2+5, 2+10, 5+2, 5+10, 10+2, 10+5 and insert them in the array as it adds them but as well check before adding if the sum is already present in the local array in which the function pushes

Comment: Want to add that this is not challenge or homework or any other variation. This is a legit question that i'm unable to find a solution to.

Comment: @user3477993 So why then wouldn't `12` be included in the resulting array?

Comment: You still need to show what you have tried regardless of why you need to solve the problem. That is how this site works...people help you fix **your code**. See [ask]

Comment: added the code above with what i tried but got stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible solution with a single loop, is to use to count from zero to `2` with the power of the item count minus one.

Basically it renders to this

```
indices  comment
-------  ---------
 0 1 2 

 0 0 0
 1 0 0
 0 1 0
 1 1 0   take this combination
 0 0 1
 1 0 1   take this combination
 0 1 1   take this combination
 1 1 1
```

```js
function getCombination(array, size) {
    var result = [],
        temp,
        i, j,
        max = 1 << array.length;

    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        temp = [];
        for (j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (i & 1 << j) {
                temp.push(array[j]);
            }
        }
        if (temp.length === size) {
            result.push(temp.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getCombination([2, 5, 10], 2));
```

You could use a recursive approach while checking the wanted length and if some values are still available.

This solution works with a nested approach for any elementsand collects them in a temporary array. If the array has the wanted lenght, then the elements are added and the result pushed to the result set.

The important part is the recursive calling with the actual element and the calling without the actual element.

```js
function getCombination(array, size) {
    function getC(temp, i) {
        if (temp.length === size) {
            result.push(temp.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }));
            return;
        }
        if (i === array.length) {
            return;
        }
        getC(temp.concat(array[i]), i + 1);
        getC(temp, i + 1);
    }

    var result = [];
    getC([], 0);
    return result;
}

console.log(getCombination([2, 5, 10], 2));
```

Comment: thank you for this. I have no idea how it works but i'll break down the code in order to better understand. Thank you for your time